# How to edit .webm files or convert them to good quality .gif, to edit in GIMP

Tags: gimp, gif, webm

I have a short scene from some TV show in a .webm format. I wanted to edit it, to create a simple funny animation/meme. I know how to edit .gif in a GIMP frame by frame, so I thought about converting this webm to gif. But the effect was very bad, here is a screenshot of .webm before conversion:

[image]

and here, after the conversion to .gif, you can see a "net", a "criss-cross" on the picture:

[image]

How can I get rid of this "net"? Or maybe it would be easier - how could I edit .webm, frame by frame, with free software? (I mean things like drawing on a frame, pasting some other picture into frames etc. not simple things like increase/decrease saturation of image, apply some filter etc, I am not interested in that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting something to GIF the quality will always drop because GIF is a very limited and old format. It's main limitation is that it only supports 256 different colors in one image in total (if the GIF is animated the color limitation AFAIR applies to each frame individually)!

PNG, JPEG and WEBM does not have this limitation and therefore an image in one of those formats usually uses "True-Color" (up to 16.7 million colors). If you convert and image that sues that much colors to a GIF the colors have to be reduced and one technique is dithering - placing pixels of different colors next to each other so that their colors mix-up if you look at the picture from a far distance. This dithering is the grid you have  noticed.

If you want to avoid the grid disable dithering or change it's settings when exporting.
See also this nice blog entries that demonstrates the effects of dithering: https://blog.littlevgl.com/2017-07-03/dithering

Comment: Actually a more recent GIF variant (20 years old, still...) supports one colormap per frame. But Gimp doesn't support that variant AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I found this article: http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html which mentions dithering and other things, and it helped me to create better quality gif :) Thanks!

In the future I should try to use .webm, but for now this solution helped me a lot.